# How can I explode/mb_split/preg_split a Chinese string with a "。" (Chinese period) as the delimiter?

Tags: php

Here is an example string in Chinese:

```
"最初 ， 上帝 创造 了 天地 。 2 大地 混沌 苍茫 ， 深渊 的 表面 一 片 黑暗 。 "
```

How can I split this into an array that looks like this?:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 最初 ， 上帝 创造 了 天地 。 2 大地 混沌 苍茫 ， 深渊 的 表面 一 片 黑暗 。
    [1] => 2 大地 混沌 苍茫 ， 深渊 的 表面 一 片 黑暗 。 
)
```

I have tried and failed with:

```
$array = mb_split('。', $string);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
```

I get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 最初 ， 上帝 创造 了 天地 。 2 大地 混沌 苍茫 ， 深渊 的 表面 一 片 黑暗 。
)
```

p.s. The charset is GB18030.

**I found more info. The Chinese period is called a full stop. The html escapes are `&#12290;` and `&#x3002;`. The GB18030 hex bytes are a1a3. The Unicode Character is 'IDEOGRAPHIC FULL STOP' (U+3002). How can I use either of these to accomplish my goal?**

Comment: Have you set `mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');` and `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");` prior to `mb_split('。', $string);`?

Comment: At your suggestion I tried: mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); and I also tried mb_regex_encoding('gb18030');
mb_internal_encoding("gb18030"); before the mb_split();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My reason for needing to do this in gb18030 is that the library I was using (dedesplit) wouldn't work when converted to utf-8. The library is a Chinese word segmenter. I contacted the developer and he informed me of a new one that does work in utf-8 (http://www.itgrass.com/phpanalysis/index.html). I have tested it and it properly explodes the paragraphs with the Chinese period (or 'full stop') as the delimiter.

p.s. Before finding this new library, I had decided to write my own explode function. I think that may have worked, but I did zero testing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array = explode(chr(227), $string);
```

---

### **Update:**

To fix the characters of `explode`:

```
foreach($array as $part) {
    echo str_replace(array(chr(128).chr(130)), '', $part);
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but no cigar. That gave me this result: `Array{[0] => 最初 ， 上帝 创造 了 天地 。 2 大地 混
    [1] => � 苍茫 ， 深渊 的 表面 一 片 黑暗 。}`

Comment: Unfortunately I have not found anything that can fix this problem in the characters with ´explode´. A NOT perfect solution is to do a str_replace on the characters that are appearing with "?" as the update.

Answer (score 0):

How about you just try

$array = explode('。', $string);

This worked for me using commandline.

Output:
Array
(
    [0] => 最初 ， 上帝 创造 了 天地 
    [1] =>  2 大地 混沌 苍茫 ， 深渊 的 表面 一 片 黑暗 
    [2] =>
)

Comment: That just gave me: Array ( [0] => 最初 ， 上帝 创造 了 天地 2 大地 混沌 苍茫 ， 深渊 的 表面 一 片 黑暗 (Could it have to do with the fact that my document is GB18030 encoded?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is `preg_split()` with the `/u` (UTF8) option, example:

```
 $s = "日、に、本、ほん、語、ご";
 $v1 = preg_split('/(?<!^)(?!$)/u', $s); // for multibyte str_split($list)
 // same as $v1=preg_split('//u', $s);array_pop($v1);array_shift($v1);
 $v2 = preg_split('/、/u', $s); // for multibyte explode("、",$list)
```

Results in

- v1 = array(12) { [0]=> string(3) "日" [1]=> string(3) "、" [2]=> string(3) "に" [3]=> string(3) "、" ... [11]=> string(3) "ご" }
- v2 = array(6) { [0]=> string(3) "日" [1]=> string(3) "に" [2]=> string(3) "本" [3]=> string(6) "ほん" [4]=> string(3) "語" [5]=> string(3) "ご" }

---

Using with your example,

```
$s = "最初 ， 上帝 创造 了 天地 。 2 大地 混沌 苍茫 ， 深渊 的 表面 一 片 黑暗 。 ";
$array  = preg_split('/。/u',$s);
var_dump($array);
```

Results

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(36) "最初 ， 上帝 创造 了 天地 " 
           [1]=> string(61) " 2 大地 混沌 苍茫 ， 深渊 的 表面 一 片 黑暗 " 
           [2]=> string(1) " " 
}
```

So, not perfect... But as a regular expresion, you can adapt it to your needs:

### Exact solution

```
$array  = preg_split('/。(?!\s*$)/u',$string);
```

now, with a [negative look ahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html), that is exctly what you need (!).

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(36) "最初 ， 上帝 创造 了 天地 " 
           [1]=> string(61) " 2 大地 混沌 苍茫 ， 深渊 的 表面 一 片 黑暗 。 " 
}
```